# Swift: TextView Font behaves differently in simulator and iPhone

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

For some reason the fontsize in my textView in a tableViewCell displays very differently in the simulator and the iPhone. The simulator appears to be correct while running the app in my iPhone seems to be wrong (the font size does not reflect the correct size).

I set the font in awakeFromNib() like so:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()  
        textView.font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 24)
    }
```

But the results are different when I run the app on my simulator and on my iPhone.

On the simulator:
[image]

On the iPhone:
[image]

Note that the textView is the one with the text "Dddddddd". Is anyone able to advice?

Comment: Are you running it on different devices and or with different layout for each devices? Such as iPhone 5 on simulator and you are using iphone 7?

Comment: @XepterX Yes indeed I am. On the simulator i run on iPhone7 and my personal iPhone is a 6s. However I have verified that even running iPhone6s on the simulator gives me the same discrepancy.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I managed to solve it by checking 'Selectable' under Behavior in Attributes inspector. Previously I unchecked it.

Comment: @REALFREE it was for me